# RecyclerView not showing the image full height

Tags: image, kotlin, android-recyclerview, image-size

I have a problem with the images inside recyclerview
[They shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jCYp.jpg)

My code to load the image is :

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage(imgUrl: String?) {

    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build().toString()


        val uiHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        thread(start = true) {
            val bitmap = downloadBitmap(imgUri)
            uiHandler.post {
                this.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            }
        }
    }


}

fun downloadBitmap(imageUrl: String): Bitmap? {
    return try {
        val conn = URL(imageUrl).openConnection()
        conn.connect()
        val inputStream = conn.getInputStream()
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
        inputStream.close()
        bitmap
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Exception $e")
        null
    }
}
```

XML for item:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_song_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:imageUrl="@{songObject.songImage}"
                android:src="@drawable/img_song_cover" />
```

And XML For Recycler:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_home_albums_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp200w"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp16w"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp16w"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8w"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_home_albums_title"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_album" />
```

My task is to do all the work without using any third-party,
So any help ?

Comment: Try adding android:adjustViewBounds="true"  and remove android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: I try it but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem just add a statement to check if the image loaded before to not render it more than once when I scroll with recycler view, and remove the place holder.

```
 if(this.drawable == null) {

        imgUrl?.let {
            val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build().toString()


            val uiHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            thread(start = true) {
                val bitmap = downloadBitmap(imgUri)
                uiHandler.post {
                    this.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```